# Requires Babel "^7.0.0-0" but was loaded with "6.26.3" while testing on a CI server

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, jestjs, babeljs

I've got a project using Vue.js, Jest, etc.

I upgrdaded webpack to 4 and Babel to 7 and experienced a lot of problems with building and running tests locally after that but eventually fixed them.

However, when I push my changes and run tests on CI, I get the following errors:

```
Test suite failed to run

Requires Babel "^7.0.0-0", but was loaded with "6.26.3". If you are sure you have a compatible version of @babel/core, it is likely that something in your build process is loading the wrong version. Inspect the stack trace of this error to look for the first entry that doesn't mention "@babel/core" or "babel-core" to see what is calling Babel.

  at throwVersionError (node_modules/@babel/helper-plugin-utils/lib/index.js:65:11)
  at Object.assertVersion (node_modules/@babel/helper-plugin-utils/lib/index.js:13:11)
  at node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-runtime/lib/index.js:86:7
  at node_modules/@babel/helper-plugin-utils/lib/index.js:19:12
      at Array.map (<anonymous>)
  at compileBabel (node_modules/vue-jest/lib/compilers/babel-compiler.js:12:21)
  at processScript (node_modules/vue-jest/lib/process.js:27:10)
  at Object.module.exports [as process] (node_modules/vue-jest/lib/process.js:49:18)
  at ScriptTransformer.transformSource (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:453:35)
  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:523:40)
  at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:579:25)
  at Object.<anonymous>.
```

package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --https --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js",
    "start": "npm run dev",
    "unit": "jest --config test/unit/jest.conf.js --coverage",
    "jest": "jest --colors --coverage test",
    "test": "npm run jest",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src test/unit",
    "lint-fix": "eslint --fix --ext .js,.vue src test/unit",
    "build": "node build/build.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.2",
    "@vue/babel-preset-app": "^3.11.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.0.0-rc.27",
    "core-js": "^2.6.9",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-cookies": "^1.5.13",
    "vue-resource": "^1.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/node": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.6.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/register": "^7.6.2",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.29",
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.1",
    "babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props": "^2.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "^1.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-jsx": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx": "^3.7.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
    "chalk": "^2.0.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "eslint": "^4.15.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^10.2.1",
    "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^2.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^5.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^4.0.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.6.1",
    "glob-all": "^3.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "jest-serializer-vue": "^0.3.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.8.0",
    "node-notifier": "^5.1.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "ora": "^1.2.0",
    "portfinder": "^1.0.13",
    "postcss-import": "^11.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.8",
    "postcss-url": "^7.2.1",
    "purgecss-webpack-plugin": "^1.6.0",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.3",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "semver": "^5.3.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.6",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "vue-jest": "^1.4.0",
    "vue-loader": "^14.2.2",
    "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.2",
    "webpack": "^4.5.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.5.2",
    "webpack-bundle-tracker": "^0.4.2-beta",
    "webpack-cli": "3.3.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.8.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 10.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 6.0.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 4 versions",
    "not ie <= 8",
    "ie >= 11"
  ],
  "jest": {
    "testURL": "http://localhost/",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "jsx",
      "vue"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.vue$": "vue-jest",
      "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
    }
  }
```

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = 
{
  "presets":
  [
    [
      "@vue/babel-preset-app", 
      {
        "modules": "commonjs",
        "targets": 
        {
          "browsers": ["> 1%", "last 4 versions", "not ie <= 8", "ie >= 11"]
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": ['@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator', '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime'],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": [
      [
        "@vue/babel-preset-app", 
        {
          "modules": "commonjs",
          "targets": {"node": "current"}
        }
      ]
    ]
    }
  }
```

}

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages:
  - test

job test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install -y curl software-properties-common
    - curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -
    - apt-get install -y nodejs build-essential
    - node -v
    - npm -v
    - npm install
    - npm run lint
    - npm run test
```

versions on server

```
$ node -v
v12.10.0
$ npm -v
6.10.3
```

Why would it work locally and not on CI? Is there something wrong in the configuration?

Comment: It would appear that `vue-jest` uses Babel 6 specifically. Maybe a newer version supports Babel 7?

Comment: Thanks! Updated vue-jest to 3 and it worked. Wonder why locally it worked with an earlier version (checked with npm list -g  -- was not globally installed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed by @loganfsmyth in comments, updated `vue-jest` version and it worked.